# mysql output to a value in the same table using a primary key with subselect

Tags: mysql

for example, how do i refer to the name son. when all i have is the mothers name **USING subselect**

```
id-Name - mother
1 -son - 2
2 -mommy  - null
```

Answer (score 1):

This is using a subselect.

```
SELECT  t.*,
        (SELECT Name FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE mother = t.id) as sons_name
FROM    TABLE_NAME as t
WHERE   t.name = 'Mommy'
```

But you could do it using a join also:

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.name as sons_name
FROM    TABLE_NAME as t1
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME as t2 ON t2.mother = t1.id
WHERE   t1.name = 'Mommy'
```